# Minimum Telerik version ASP AJAX for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, telerik, runtime-error, undefined

I started using Visual Studio 2013 today and from the get-go I'm having Telerik Issues. All javascript bombs out with message:

```
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'documentElement' of undefined or null reference

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

The solution works fine in VS2012 though.

All searches point to Telerik being the problem.

What is the minimum Telerik Version required for Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Which version of the Telerik UI libraries are you using?

What does your markup look like?

Comment: Ver 2010.3 which is obviously too old. In Visual Studio 2012 it works perfectly, in VS2013 the exact same project gives mentioened error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio version shouldn't be the reason for the error, but most likely the .NET version. The error is discussed in [this forum thread](http://www.telerik.com/forums/using-telerik---0x800a138f---javascript-runtime-error-unable-to-get-property-documentelement-of-undefined-or-null-reference) and the solution is to upgrade at least to version Q3 2013 (2013.3.1114).